# Change value with the API

Tags: javascript, api

I wanted to change the value of json lottie files to a new value using the API. This is the code that was found for this, but it did not work. Thanks for any help.

```
import LottieWebParser from 'lottie-web-parser';
import animationData from './data.js';
let colorInfo = LottieWebParser.parseColors(animationData);
LottieWebParser.replaceColor([255, 0, 0, 1], colorInfo[0].path, animationData);
```

Comment: You will need to post the definition of `animationData` imported from "./data.js", at the minimum.

Comment: How to define it ?

Comment: Obtaining the definition does not imply *you* define it -- you are importing it from "./data.js", so there should be a definition of it in that module. It would be useful to be able to look at the definition, in order to help you.

Comment: Before sending the code, I put the file path I wanted but it did not work. I manually gave the color file to the class. Should I not put it in the third line and I wrote a color editor with js to change the color of the file. I had to change the color with the API and download the new file, but I did not succeed in the download

Comment: I don't know, frankly -- it's hard to help you troubleshoot code when I don't know what `animationData` refers to. You have a copy of `./data.js` -- why don't you locate the definition of `animationData` there? Did you write the module? Is it published anywhere I can locate it and find the definition of `animationData` myself? I understand that "lottie-web-parser" *is* some published module, so I don't need you to help me with those definitions, but `./data.js` looks to be something else, something that may not be published anywhere, and to understand your code its definition is needed.